# Entity Framework join with table-valued function with parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, user-defined-functions

I have a table value function `foo(int id)` and I added it to my context (and it will return only 1 row, due to Entity Framework limitation on scalar functions).

Then I want to join `mytable` with `foo` passing `id` of my table to it

I tried

```
var result = context.MyTable
             .Select(obj => new 
             {
                x = obj,
                y = context.foo(obj.id)
             }
```

Then I tried to use join, like below

```
var result = context.MyTable
             .Join(context.foo(obj.id), ....
```

but I don't have access to MyTable data in join

Any solution?

Comment: @igor these are different questions, they are not duplicate

Comment: @igor, my question is how to pass value to tvf parameter, then I tried to say what I have done till now